# How to calculate ALL gps data from CLLocationManager at the same time

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I need to calculate ALL gps parameters in my program so I use this piece of code:

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject];
```

which collects all the gps measurements (altitude, speed, etc) in loc object and I have the lat/long info (`loc.coordinate.lattitude` and `loc.coordinate.longitude`) but these are the NEW measured coordinates.

As I also want to calculate distance between measurements how can I retrieve both the "new" coordinates and the "old" coordinates from the `didUpdateLocations` method?

If I add another locationManager call with the didUpdateToLocation method in the program (which will give old and new coordinates):

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
```

the initial locationManager method (didUpdateLocations) is not called at all, so I cannot calculate all gps data plus distance...

Comment: The second method you listed is deprecated - replaced by the first, but if you implement it then the first method isn't called - as you found.  You need to store the previous location in a property and compare/calculate based on this on the next call

Comment: As I am new to iOS programming, how do I copy the location object to another object (i.e. the old location) with visibility outside the CLLocationManage (so I can compare the latest location data on the next CLLocationManager method call)? I get access to the lat/long properties of the loc object but the CLLocationDistance method I will call requires  objects as arguments, not properties.

Comment: Just create a property for your class that stores a CLLocation

Answer (score 0):

After succeeding with the property copy I have this working code but I cannot make sense of:

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
  _locManagerIteration++;
  NSLog(@"Location manager iteration = %ld", _locManagerIteration);

  CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject];           // locations is guaranteed to have at least one object

  if (_locManagerIteration == 1) {                    //INITIALIZE THE FIRST PAST COORDINATE OBJECT
      self.pastCoordinate = [locations lastObject];
  } else {
      CLLocationDistance _pointDistance = [self.pastCoordinate distanceFromLocation:loc];
      NSLog(@"POINT TO POINT DISTANCE = %f", _pointDistance);
      self.pastCoordinate = [locations lastObject];
  }
  NSLog(@"POINT TO POINT DISTANCE = %f", _pointDistance);

  _totalDistance = _totalDistance + _pointDistance;   //COMPUTE TOTAL DISTANCE
  _totalDistance = _totalDistance / 1000;             //TRANSLATE TOTAL DISTANCE IN KILOMETERS
  In the above section, CLLocationDistance call correctly places the distance in meters in my global variable _pointDistance. I print the _pointDistance variable and see the number (NSLog...). HOWEVER, when I again print the same global variable outside the if-then statement the value is always zero...

Within the else bracket the _pointDistance variable has a black color in XCODE (and prints the value) and outside the else bracket is showed with green color and the value is zeroed.... Can't make any sense out of it...